# Creating a lot number using Julian/Ordinal date from a yyyy-mm-dd and concatenate in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create a lot number which consists of:

Digits: 1,2,3 ----> Three digit reagent code ----> For example:141 (this is a constant)

Digit: 4 ----> Identifier ----> For example: 2 (this is a constant)

Digits: 5,6,7 ----> Julian/Ordinal Calendar day ----> 001-365 (366 for leap year)

Digit: 8 ----> The last digit of the expiry year ----> 0-9

Therefore: **14120039** (Expiry date would be **2019-01-03**)

The expiry date can be found on a sheet called "CP_sequencer" in cell "S7".  This will be in the format yyyy-mm-dd.

The following is the code I’m using so far but I know something is wrong and it may not be the most efficient way of doing things.  There are a few cell references that are correct but I know it may be hard to follow without the actual spreadsheet.

```
Dim Julian_Day As String
Dim Split_Date As String
Dim valueYear, valueLastDigit As Integer

Range("F31").Select
Julian_Day = _
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VALUE(RIGHT(YEAR('CP sequencer'!R[-24]C[13]),2)&TEXT('CP sequencer'!R[-24]C[13]-DATE(YEAR('CP sequencer'!R[-24]C[13]),1,0),""000""))"
Split_Date = _
Range("F31") = Year(CP_Sequencer.Range("S7"))

Range("F31").Select
Select Case Len(value1) 'gives a number depending on the length of the value1
Case 4 ' e.g., 2017 = 201, 7
    valueYear = Left(value1, 3) ' 201
    valueLastDigit = Right(value1, 7) ' 7
End Select

ActiveCell.Value = "1412" & Julian_Day & valueLastDigit
```

I know something isn't right because at the moment when I run this code the output is **1412False0**

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: what do you "know is wrong"?

Comment: and you're right, definitely can't help you calculate something without knowing what we're working with.  Where do these values come from? (ie., reageant, identifier) Is Julian date based on current date or expiry date.  Where does expiry date come from?  More info and a screen shot might help.  (also check out [mcve])You have 2 lines like ***something = something = something***.  Assign values to only 1 variable.

Comment: @ashleedawg I have edited my question, if you need more info please just let me know.  The date I'm changing to a Julian/ordinal date is an expiry date which can be found on a sheet called CP_Sequencer in cell "S7".

Answer (score 0):

This should return the LotNumber you're after.
I'm quite not sure what's wrong with your code, but it will be in this line:

```
Julian_Day = _
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VALUE(RIGHT(YEAR('CP sequencer'!R[-24]C[13]),2)&TEXT('CP sequencer'!R[-24]C[13]-DATE(YEAR('CP sequencer'!R[-24]C[13]),1,0),""000""))"
```

This is asking the question **is the formula in the activecell the same as the text string "=VALUE(RIGHT...."** and place the result in the Julian_Day variable. Pretty much guaranteed that the value won't be the same so `FALSE` is returned.
If you wanted to get the result of the formula using that method you'd need to place the formula in the cell first and then read the result... but I'd advise against using that method.  Easier to reference the values within VBA.

The LotNumber function below should return the value you're after.  You can use it as I have in the Test procedure or as a worksheet function entered directly in a cell:  `=LotNumber(A1,B1,C1)`

```
Sub Test()

    'Passing values to the LotNumber function.
    Debug.Print LotNumber(141, 2, DateValue("3 January 2019"))

    'Getting values from Sheet1.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Debug.Print LotNumber(.Range("A1"), .Range("B1"), .Range("C1"))
    End With

End Sub

Public Function LotNumber(Reagent As Long, Identifier As Long, Expiry As Date) As String

    Dim Ordinal As Long

    Ordinal = Expiry - DateSerial(Year(Expiry), 1, 1) + 1

    LotNumber = Format$(Reagent, "000") & Identifier & Format$(Ordinal, "000") & Right(Format(Expiry, "yyyy"), 1)

End Function
```

**Edit:**
As an afterthought you could define the LotNumber function as:

```
Public Function LotNumber(Expiry As Date, Optional Reagent As Long = 141, Optional Identifier As Long = 2) As String
```

Using this method you must pass the date to the function, but the `Reagent` and `Identifier` will default to *141* and *2* if no alternative values are supplied.
If entered today (30th November 17) then `Debug.Print LotNumber(Date)` will return `14123347`.  As a worksheet function with 3rd Jan 2019 in cell C1:  `=LotNumber(C1)` will return *14120039*

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a VBA solution to write back your lot number code to a given cell. Your code includes many errors (references without values, undeclared variables, double assignments and so on). Maybe the code with explainations below will be of some help. I use a type Definition to structure your results and make the code more readable.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit   ' obliges you to declare your variables
    Type TData     ' declaration head of your module
        ReagentCode As String   ' 3 dig .. 141
        ID          As String   ' 1 dig .. 2
        JulDays     As String   ' 3 dig .. 1-365/366
        YearDigit   As String   ' 1 dig .. 7 (2017 -> 7)
    End Type

Sub CreateLotNo()
' Declare variables
  Dim MyData     As TData
  Dim yr         As Integer      ' expiry year extracted from cell Sz
  Dim ws         As Worksheet
' set fully qualified reference to your worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CP Sequencer")
' get expiry year from cell S7
  yr = Year(ws.Range("S7").Value)   ' expiry year
With MyData
' assign values to MyData
  .ReagentCode = "141"            ' constant
  .ID = "2"                       ' constant
  ' julian days = expiry date minus last year's ultimo date
  .JulDays = Format(ws.Range("S7").Value - CDate("12.31." & yr - 1), "000")
  .YearDigit = Right(yr, 1)       ' last digit of the expiry year
' write lot number back to cell XY
  ws.Range("F31").Value = .ReagentCode & .ID & .JulDays & .YearDigit & ""
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried your code I seem to get an error on the following line: `.JulDays = Format(ws.Range("S7").Value - CDate("12.31." & yr - 1), "000")`  I'm quite new to VBA and learning as I go and cant quite spot the error

Comment: Code was working for me. - Does your S7 cell actually contain a date value? Try also to use "/" or "-" instead of points "." in the `CDate` portion.

Comment: You could try to use `DateSerial` instead of `CDate` (cf. @Darren-Bartrup-Cook 's Approach) : `.JulDays = Format(ws.Range("S7").Value - DateSerial(yr, 1, 1) + 1, "000")` - pay attention to the leading point before `.JulDays`, too. But check the date value in S7 as well.

Comment: The expiry date in cell S7 is calculated using a formula, would this effect the code? The formula takes the min date of 3 individual expiry dates and applies that as the expiry date to a product.  Would I then have to convert the date in S7 so that the cell sees a date value rather than the formula?

Comment: No, if it's a date (= numeric value).